# Dry up custom wrappers in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Rather than having almost two similar custom wrapper definition, is it possible to dry them up? for e.g:

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input, :wrap_with => { :class => 'checkbox inline' }
      ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }          
    end
  end
```

and

```
config.wrappers :inline_checkbox_two, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_class => 'error' do |b|
    b.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
    # everything else should use the same definition as the above
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a module to DRY it out:

```
module WrapperHelper

  # options:
  #   - wrapper [Hash]
  #   - label_input [Hash]
  #   - error [Hash]
  #   - use [Array] an array of arguments to pass to b.use
  def self.inline_checkbox(b, **kwargs)
    if kwargs[:use]
      b.use *kwargs[:use]
    else
      b.use :html5
    end
    wrapper_opts = {
      tag: 'div',
      class: 'control-group'
      error_class: 'error'
    }.merge(kwargs[:wrapper] || {}) # merge defaults with passed `wrapper` keyword argument
    b.wrapper(wrapper_opts) do |ba|
      ba.use :label_input, 
        { wrap_with: { class: 'checkbox inline' } }.merge(kwargs[:label_input] || {})
      ba.use :error, 
        { wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' } }.merge(kwargs[:error] || {})
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
config.wrappers :html5_inline_checkbox do |b|
  WrapperHelper.inline_checkbox(b)
end

config.wrappers :inline_checkbox_with_helper do |b|
  WrapperHelper.inline_checkbox(b, use: [:hint, {wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }}])
end
```

Comment: This uses a bit of destructuring and ruby 2.0 keyword arguments. You can read more about it here: http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html and here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments